# Rails public profile creation and determining whether profile is public or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, callback

In my app a user has the ability to create a profile, but there is a series of required fields that need to be filled out before the user's profile is "public".

I am working on an `after_update` callback that runs a series of checks to see if the required fields are filled out.

Here is the method:

```
# User Model
after_update :check_public_status

def check_public_status
    if self.name.blank? || self.state.blank? || self.city.blank? || 
        self.high_school.blank? || self.recruit_year.blank? || self.birthday.blank? || 
        self.stat(:height).blank? || self.stat(:weight).blank?
      self.update_attribute :public, false
      self.update_attribute :removed_from_listing, true
    else
      self.update_attribute :public, true
      self.update_attribute :removed_from_listing, false
    end
  end
```

Is there a better way of doing this without having that nasty `IF/Else` statement?

Comment: What about--    if "".in?([self.name,self.state,self.city,self.high_school])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

#### User Model

```
after_update :update_public_status!

def update_public_status!
  required_fields_present = 
    [
      name, state, city, 
      high_school, recruit_year,
      birthday, stat(:height), stat(:weight)
    ].all?
  if required_fields_present
    make_public!
  else
    make_private!
  end
end

def make_public!
  update_attribute :public, true
  update_attribute :removed_from_listing, false
end

def make_private!
  update_attribute :public, false
  update_attribute :removed_from_listing, true
end
```